# How to correctly bind values of id and data-target with angular2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, ngfor

Am trying to bind values of id and data-target to show bootstrap modal for each item in ngFor:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of jobsList; let i = index" class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-header">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p [innerHTML]="item.description" class="card-text"></p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#' + i">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" [attr.id]="i" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle" [innerHTML]="item.name"></h5>
```

the above code doesn't work, why?